# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 when trying to create CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer

Tags: java, eclipse, oauth

EDIT:

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("debug1");
    CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer("key","secret");
         System.out.println("debug2");
...}
```

hi when i try to run this script i get this response:

debug1

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64

at oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner.<init>(OAuthMessageSigner.java:37)

at oauth.signpost.signature.HmacSha1MessageSigner.<init>(HmacSha1MessageSigner.java:30)

at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthConsumer.<init>(AbstractOAuthConsumer.java:65)

at oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer.<init>(CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer.java:30)

at mein.tester.main(tester.java:21)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)

... 5 more
```

Line 21 is the line before

```
         System.out.println("debug2");
```

Well i can easily compile the code in eclipse and i added 2 Signpost librabrys and also common-codec.jar as external library as i read in another post.. however, how do i make it available on runtime?(i did like in the post "add it to WEB-INF/lib " -> i created that folder and added the jar
-i also tryed the defaultoauthconsumer -> same error

Comment: Are all of the necessary jars in your classpath?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the jar and choose "add to build path"? I don't think the ide will automatically add it to your classpath unless you tell it to.

Comment: yeah they are all added to classpath(rightclick on project properties ->built java path ->librarys add external jar... and i also tryed rightclicking them and add to built path .. now i have them 2 times in

Comment: Adding it as an external jar is only appropriate if it is located outside of your workspace. Putting it in web-inf/lib is only appropriate if you are deploying it as a web app. Have you tried calling something like Base64.decodeBase64(string) - from your main method -that is a good test to see if it is on your classpath. Is it definitely in the same project as your Main class?  Alternatively, have you looked in the codecs jar to see if that class is there? It could be an issue with using the wrong version of the jar.

Comment: thank you you were right, i checked the commons.jar and there were only .html files... after i downloaded a new common codec+ added it+ticked it; it works... i hope i can debug the rest on my own now)